# Getting a tire off the rim - 37-622

Tags: road-bike, tire, rims

Ive tried everything and can’t seem to get the tire off the rim. I’ve double checked the bead and it’s loose. I pushed the beads into the centre.  I’ve tried warming up the tire. It almost seems the tire is smaller than the rim. I try and use the tire leaver to lift it but it almost seems to grab both beads at the same time. I can’t lift one bead up over the rim edge. I really don’t want to take it into a shop as I’ve changed other tires quite easily. I also tried the front tire Incase it was just an issue with the rear one I was working on. Natta. Any suggestions?

---

Soap and a bunch of muscle power did the trick. Thanks so much everyone.

Comment: If the lever is grabbing both beads at the same time, you likely won't be able to get the slack you need if it's tight. You could try pushing hard on it to fold it over until you get the shot you need at jamming the lever under what you can see is just one bead. Also, if someone installed 700C tires on a 27" rim, impossible or nearly impossible removal situations can be the result - does the rim say 27" or 630 anywhere on it? Is it an old rim?

Comment: Try to grab only one bead. Try inserting a second lever right beside the first one and then lift them over the rim edge.

Comment: On the positive side, just remember - it went on somehow, so it can come off.

Comment: To get maximum leverage the bead should not be too far away from the rim - just far enough to get a tyre lever under it.

Comment: If an existing answer isn't sufficient, you should submit your own answer and the "accept" it.

Answer (score 4):

Counterintuitively, one pump of air in the tube may help separate the two beads of the tyre, allowing you to grab just one with the tip of your tyre lever.

I have a bunch of tyre levers, and some are good while others are dreadful.    See if you have one with a flattish front, not a spoon or bill shape.

It can help to use some cable ties or velcro straps to squash the tyre into the rim's internal valley.  Then work your way around the tyre pushing the whole thing into the rim whilst moving the excess around the circumference to the opposite side.  This is generally how one would fit a new tight tyre like a Marathon.  You're doing the same process in the same order but aiming to get the bead off.

Last resort, if the tyre's dead you can cut it off but this means the tyre can't be reused,

Answer (score -1):

You need a tire prying tool. Please make sure you remove the stem and the valve before removing it. If it is not possible go to the repair facility it will be simple and cheap.

Comment: How is the tire prying tool different from tire lever, and how does one remove valve without removing the tire first?

Comment: @ojs you can sometimes pull out the valve in a tubeless set up without getting either bead off. But I don't think that's the case here. I'm also not sure what the distinction is between valve and stem in this answer.